# select range from dual in mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I am using MariaDB and I would like to generate a dummy result set of a number range. The following works well:

```
select 0.0 as x
union select 0.1
union select 0.2
union select 0.3
union select 0.4
union select 0.5
union select 0.6
union select 0.7
union select 0.8
union select 0.9
union select 1.0
from dual
```

But is there a shorter form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MariaDB 10.1+ you can use a [Sequence table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/):

```
SELECT 0.1 * seq AS col
FROM seq_0_to_10
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b0cbd3ed4da4d3204df1a7f9d2978c38).

Answer (score 2):

Using `VALUES`:

```
VALUES (0.0),(0.1),(0.2),(0.3),(0.4),(0.5),(0.6),(0.7),(0.8),(0.9),(1.0)
```

It makes sense when the list is static.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bb0ef7b2ef72b9b6b45dcea64779217b)**

---

MySQL version will require adding `ROW`

```
VALUES ROW(0.0), ROW(0.1), ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive CTE here:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS (
    SELECT 0.0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 0.1 FROM cte WHERE n < 1.0
)

SELECT * FROM cte;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo